# RavenDB automation - RESTful way to add users to system db for Windows Authentication?

Tags: ravendb

**Situation:**

Automated commercial RavenDB 3 server install & configuration on Amazon EC2 to a standalone server (no active directory domain).  Local Windows users are automatically created.

**Problem:**

Using the HTTP client API, how to add local windows users to the `Raven/Authorization/WindowsSettings` document of the `system` database?

**Reference:**

The docs describe a method using the Studio to achieve this: 
https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/http/server/configuration/authentication-and-authorization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document is just that, a standard RavenDB document. You can operate on that using the standard JSON REST endpoints to manipulate it.

Comment: When making GET requests to the endpoint:

http://localhost:8080/databases/system/docs?id=Raven/Authorization/WindowsSettings

 I seem to always get the following response:

`{
  "Error": "Could not find a database named: system"
}`

Comment: kwoods, for the system database, I believe you are to omit the "databases/system" part. That is, try http://localhost:8080/docs?id=Raven/Authorization/WindowsSettings

Comment: Looks like I was missing the angle brackets around "system".  This endpoint is now working for me.  Thanks to you both!  http://localhost:8080/databases/<system>/docs?id=Raven/Authorization/WindowsSettings